# Java: ArrayLists help, references

Tags: java

**Class A:**
Contains a filled arraylist of Employee objects which each contain employeeName and employeeNumber

Is it possible for **Class B** to create a variable that references class A's arraylist of Employee objects? I only need to search that arraylist. Maybe print it. Not change anything in it.

Any strategies or examples of how I could do this?

Comment: What is List vs ArrayList?

Comment: List is Interface and ArrayList is a Class..  :-P better learn java from headfirst java book

Answer (score 2):

```
    package p1;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;



    public class ArrayReference {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new BB().method();
        }
    }


    class AA {
        private List list = new ArrayList();

        public List getEmpList() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        }

    }

    class BB {
        public void method() {
            List list = new AA().getEmpList();
            list.add(new Emp()); // here runtime exception will occour if we
            // try to add objects in list.
            // java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException is an exception for add
            // method in list

        }
    }

    class Emp {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a getter method on class A that exposes the `ArrayList` and simply call the getter from Class B

```
class A { 
    List myList...;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() { 
    ...
    }
}

class B { 
    A handleToA;

    public void search() { 
        handleToA.getEmployees()...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just have to allow `Class A` to share the `ArrayList` with `Class B`. You can do this by creating a `public` *getter* method in `Class A` that returns the `ArrayList` to any other class that requests it.

```
Class A
{
   private List<Employee> employees;

   public A() {
     this.employees = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public List<Employee> getEmployees(){ return this.employees; } 
}
```

Now `Class B` can ask for the employees `ArrayList` by calling `getEmployees()`

```
Class B
{
   private A a;

   public B() {
     this.a = new A();

     // fill the list ...

     List<Employee> fromA = a.getEmployees();  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a getter in Class A, no need to duplicate the same in ClassB

```
class A {
    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        return employeeList;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Class A {
   private List<Employees> empList = new ArrayList<Employees>();

   //Setters
   //Getters

   //Load data to empList
}

Class B {

  void empList() {
      A empClass = new A();

      List<Employees> empListFromClassA = new ArrayList<Employees>();
      empListFromClassA.addAll(getEmpList()); //Getter from class A
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

if you want only search in list use this:

class A { 
    List myList...;

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees() { 
    return myList.clone();
}
```

}

and this returns clone of your list. If you change clone original list stay the same

Answer (score 1):

create a public getter method in Class A and acces the same via Class B.

```
class A{
  private List<Employee> employees;

  public List getEmployees(){ return this.employees;}
}


class B{
  private List<Employee> employees;

  public B(){ 
  A a  = new A();
  employees = a.getEmployees();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Phenomenon you are trying to acheive is "Encapsulation".
In java we can achieve this by implementing Getter and setter method is Plain java objects.
Getter and setter play very important role in java application development.

You can implement solution like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class A {
    private List<String> empList = new ArrayList<String>();
    A(){
        empList.add("Employee 1");
        empList.add("Employee 2");
        empList.add("Employee 3");
        empList.add("Employee 4");
        empList.add("Employee 5");

    }
    public List<String> getEmpList() {
        return empList;
    }

    public void setEmpList(List<String> empList) {
        this.empList = empList;
    }
}

class B {
    void empList() {
        A empClass = new A();
        List<String> empListFromClassA = empClass.getEmpList();     
        System.out.println("This is what you need ? "+ empListFromClassA.toString());
    }
}

public class TEST{
    public static void main(String Args[]){
        B classb = new B();
        classb.empList();
    }
}
```